# double HTML Meta after include

Tags: php, include, double, meta, doctype

I hope you can help me!

My header has this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Along with some css links.

When I use this header with include into my other pages, I get in my code source:
`double <!doctype html> , <meta title>...`

I think this is not very a good method to do...

Do you know how can I include my header on pages without those double information displayed?

```
<?php
include("./include/header.php");
require_once("./Modele/lesverites.php");

// lesverites
function listesVerites(){

    $lesverites = getLesVerites();
    require_once("./lesverites.php");
    return $lesverites;
   
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any `<!DOCTYPE html.>...` in the file you include this from (or any other potential files you're including). Without seeing the code that includes this, that's about as specific I can get.

Comment: So i can't use <link > css in <head> on my other page with the header ?

Comment: Please post all relevant code (like where you include this) so we can see what actually happens. We need to see the context and how you're doing this. Also post the complete file you're including. Just seeing snippets doesn't tell us as much.

Comment: i eddited my post, not sure this can help you

Comment: If you get `<!DOCTYPE html>` etc twice, then you either have that in multiple files you include or you include header twice. Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we're kind of stuck.

Comment: I got <!DOCTYPE html> on my header page and in my other page verite.php
the code is too long i can't post it, it made some errors.
Should I remove the <!doctype> from others page ? how can i add CSS to the other page without the <head> ?